# Replacing Smart Quote ( ” ) in NSString - Replace doesn't catch it

Tags: objective-c, macos, plugins

I'm try to catch and replace smart quotes in my Objective-C code and have been unsuccessful. I've attempted to using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString and it doesn't appear to catch it. I've tried to catch it with the unicode value and the ASCII character.

An example of input would be:

> Unable to complete operation -  You don’t have permission to save the
>   file “Test” in the folder “Desktop”.

Here is my existing function in attempts to cleanup various NSString values:

```
NSString* ScrubStringForInvalidCharacters(NSString* buffer)
{
    NSString *result = buffer;
    NSLog(@"%@",result);
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u2013" withString:@"-"];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u2013" withString:@"-"];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u2014" withString:@"-"];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u2015" withString:@"-"];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u2017" withString:@"_"];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u2018" withString:@"\'"];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u2019" withString:@"\'"];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u201a" withString:@","];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u201b" withString:@"\'"];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u201c" withString:@"\""];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u201d" withString:@"\""];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u201e" withString:@"\""];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u2026" withString:@"..."];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u2032" withString:@"\'"];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u2033" withString:@"\""];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"“" withString:@"\""];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"”" withString:@"\""];
    NSLog(@"%@",result);
    return result;
}
```

Here is what the NSLogs return:

> 2016-09-27 09:00:30.811 ...[3388:183176] Unable to complete operation -  You don’t have permission to save the file “Test” in the folder “Desktop”.
>
> 2016-09-27 09:00:30.812 ...[3388:183176] Unable to complete operation -  You don’t have permission to save the file “Test” in the folder “Desktop”.

If I don't end up capturing and replacing the smart quotes, my application ends up displaying:

[Error Message on Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8kKw.png)

This error is generated when I use NSFileManager createDirectoryAtPath. I then capture an error and send the localizedDescription to the the ScrubStringForInvalidCharacters function.

Thanks!
- Jeff

Comment: Cannot reproduce, `“Test” in the folder “Desktop”` is replaced by `"Test" in the folder "Desktop"` in my test.

Comment: Odd, thanks for testing it out Martin.